# Grub is showing Ubuntu but not loading it

Tags: boot, grub2

First of all thanks to all sharing all kinds of useful info.
   I have one similar problem, want to take inputs from you.
   In my Laptop I am using wind7 and Ubuntu12.04 as dual boot.
   it worked fine many days, recently I am seeing one problem.
   Grub is showing both Wind7 and Ubuntu in boot options, but when I select Ubuntu it is loading only black screen with white cursor blinking. If I select wind7 it is loading wind correctly and working fine. Only problem with Ubuntu loading.
   It worked previously, now only it is giving problem. What way I have to proceed. I need inputs from you.
   As I have important data in Ubuntu partition I don't want to experiment my own loosing data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions which are as simple as they are safe.

1. From grub, navigate to *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and try using an older kernel. (This has been a reoccuring theme throughout my endeavors.)
2. On 12.04 you should be running Upstart by default. Not entirely too likely but if by chance you somehow switched to systemd, navigate to *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and select an option that states Upstart will be used. (upstart and systemd handle the starting of services during boot)
3. If you have a black screen with a visible cursor, there could be an issue with your display manager. When you arrive at this part, bypass xserver by entering a virtual terminal by pressing `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1`. Login with your credentials and type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Selecting your display manager will revert any accidental changes back to their default settings. `ctrl`+`alt`+`F7` will take you back to the graphical interface.